# Gulp displays BrowserSnyc Page not my index.html

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I'm new to gulp and browsersync. I installed react-bootstrap-starter ( https://github.com/jogleasonjr/react-bootstrap-starter )
on an ubuntu 16.04 instance on AWS.

To get the program to display on my web browser over the internet I added:

```
ui: {
            port: 80
        },
```

to "gulp/config.js". Here's the total file contents:

```
var dest = './build',
    src = './src';

module.exports = {
    browserSync: {
        ui: {
            port: 80
        },
        server: {
            baseDir: [dest, src]
        },
        files: [
            dest + '/**'
        ]

    },
    less: {
        src: src + '/less/main.less',
        watch: [
            src + '/less/**'
        ],
        dest: dest
    },
    markup: {
        src: src + "/www/**",
    dest: dest
    },
    browserify: {
        // Enable source maps
        debug: true,
        // A separate bundle will be generated for each
        // bundle config in the list below
        bundleConfigs: [{
            entries: src + '/app/app.jsx',
            dest: dest,
            outputName: 'app.js'
        }]
    }
};
```

The contents of "gulp/tasks/browserSync.js" is:

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var config      = require('../config').browserSync;

gulp.task('browserSync', ['build'], function() {
  browserSync(config);
});
```

When I run "sudo gulp" I get this on my terminal:

```
[20:48:12] Using gulpfile /nodeB2/react-bootstrap-starter/gulpfile.js
[20:48:12] Starting 'setWatch'...
[20:48:12] Finished 'setWatch' after 96 μs
[20:48:12] Starting 'browserify'...
[20:48:12] Bundling app.js...
[20:48:12] Starting 'markup'...
[20:48:12] Starting 'less'...
[20:48:12] Finished 'markup' after 161 ms
[20:48:12] Finished 'less' after 155 ms
[20:48:16] Bundled app.js in 4.33 s
[20:48:16] Finished 'browserify' after 4.34 s
[20:48:16] Starting 'build'...
[20:48:16] Finished 'build' after 3.44 μs
[20:48:16] Starting 'browserSync'...
[20:48:16] Finished 'browserSync' after 25 ms
[20:48:16] Starting 'watch'...
[20:48:16] Finished 'watch' after 13 ms
[20:48:16] Starting 'default'...
[20:48:16] Finished 'default' after 14 μs
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 -------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://172.30.0.233:3000
 -------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:80
 UI External: http://172.30.0.233:80
 -------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./build
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./src
[Browsersync] Watching files...
[Browsersync] Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)
```

When I go to my browser I see a file, but it is a generic browserSync file, not my html file in "build/index.html".

Why doesn't it show my html file instead and where is this file coming from?

Comment: What if you added the "index" option to the browserSync "server" config.  So right under baseDir.  index: [html file to open]?  Does that  help?

Comment: normally browserify input is your entry point like "app.js" and its output should be a bundle in /dest that is called by the html file or index.html.  spend some more time understanding what gulp does in your browserify step and u may get the correct output for index.html

Comment: Added the "index: dest + '/**'  option with the same results. 

Not sure what the second post means. " build/app.js" is a huge file, I wouldn't know where to track down what's happening in that file. The index.html file is in the build directory also, which I assume is correct. I'm not sure what other files to look in to find the error. Besides, the reason I picked this program to install is to look at a simple working react + bootstrap program to try and understand, not to find a program that needs debugging. Maybe there's a simpler working example out there that I could start with.